# Can i use fonts in GIMP without even installing them?

Tags: windows, fonts, gimp

I have downloaded few fonts. I want to use them in GIMP, but google says i have to install them to use them. Isn't it possible to copy these font to some folder and tell GIMP to use that folder or else there will be too much fonts in windows/fonts directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried it but it looks like this is what you want.
http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-fonts.html
Along with the companion volume
http://www.gimp.org/unix/fonts.html

Comment: Thats what i  want :)